# Next.js loading custom fonts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components, font-face

How do I use custom fonts with nextjs in general and how to make it work with styled-components?

Expecting for the loaded fonts to be available in css. I've tried:

- linking .css file with fonts loaded using `@font-face` in _document's  component - it loads the file but fonts do not work
- linking .woff2 files in `_document.tsx`'s  component - it loads the file but fonts do not work
- used localFont from `@next/font/local` - nothing
- used @font-face in globalStyles from `styled-components` - nada
- used `<style jsx global>` and defined css variables on `:root` - zilch
- tried setting font-family for html elements inline - still does not use the font

The project is inside a nx monorepo.

Comment: i'm having issues with nextjs generating production css that's pointing to webpack's devServer when i load a local font from css. i'm wasting so much time because custom webpack configurations appear to be overwritten by miniCssExtractPlugin